# Unable to build my Vuejs application using npm run build

Tags: vue.js, webpack

When I run `npm run build` in my Vuejs application I get the following error:

```
compiler.hooks.compilation.tap(
^
TypeError: Cannot read property 'compilation' of undefined
at OptimizeCssAssetsWebpackPlugin.apply (C:\Users\EFOSA\Desktop\my_project\client\node_modules\last-call-webpack-plugin\src\index.js:170:20)
at Compiler.apply (C:\Users\EFOSA\Desktop\my_project\client\node_modules\tapable\lib\Tapable.js:375:16)
at webpack (C:\Users\EFOSA\Desktop\my_project\client\node_modules\webpack\lib\webpack.js:33:19)
at err (C:\Users\EFOSA\Desktop\my_project\client\build\build.js:19:3)
at next (C:\Users\EFOSA\Desktop\my_project\client\node_modules\rimraf\rimraf.js:75:7)
at CB (C:\Users\EFOSA\Desktop\my_project\client\node_modules\rimraf\rimraf.js:111:9)
at C:\Users\EFOSA\Desktop\my_project\client\node_modules\rimraf\rimraf.js:137:14
at FSReqWrap.oncomplete (fs.js:154:21)
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 1
npm ERR! my_project@1.0.0 build: node build/build.js
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Failed at the my_project@1.0.0 build script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR! C:\Users\EFOSA\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache_logs\2019-07-02T07_51_40_908Z-debug.log
```

I'm running webpack 3.12.
Could someone please help me with this?

Answer (score 1):

There is a problem with your configuration and/or plugin version. Check the [optimize-css-assets-webpack-plugin](https://github.com/NMFR/optimize-css-assets-webpack-plugin) documentation:

> For webpack v3 or below please use
>   optimize-css-assets-webpack-plugin@3.2.0. The
>   optimize-css-assets-webpack-plugin@4.0.0 version and above supports
>   webpack v4.

Comment: thanks for the detail information detailed information